# Updating OpenSSL on Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, openssl, strawberry-perl, heartbleed-bug

I have a portable Strawberry Perl version 5.18.1.1 which has OpenSSL Version 1.0.1e and I want to update it to 1.0.1g.  Could someone help?  What should I do in order to update my Strawberry Perl to OpenSSL 1.0.1g, including all the modules that depend on this library such as crypt::ssleay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Strawberry Perl 5.18.2.2, which was released on April 15.  It has OpenSSL 1.0.1g, which includes a fix to the Heartbleed bug.